# How to load a script tag after loading all components in Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In `wwwroot/index.html` (Blazor WebAssembly) or `Pages/_Host.cshtml` (Blazor Server) we can add a `<script src="?"/>` tag.

```html
<body>
    ...

    <script src="_framework/blazor.{webassembly|server}.js"></script>
    <script src="?"></script> // I want to load this script after all components/site completely loaded.
</body>
```

But the problem is the `<script src="?"/>` tag just loaded but I want to load it after loading all components of Blazor. (Some functions inside the script cannot find some elements)

There is a way to load a JS `function` like below

```cs
@page "/"

 @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

    <div>
        this is index page
    </div>
@code {

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initilizeNiceAdminJs");// Initialize main.js after site completely loaded
        }
    }
}
```

The `OnAfterRenderAsync` method helps us to load a JS function after loading entire components in the Blazor.

Does exist any way to do the same with a `<script src="?"/>` tags instead of a function?

Comment: Did you try whether `<script defer src...` helps? Just suggesting...

Comment: Why not put the JS code you want to run into a function that you load as normal, and then call that function from `OnAfterRenderAsync`?

Comment: @Ergis `defer` does not work.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis script is minified and huge not possible for all scenarios.

Comment: take a look at https://www.geekinsta.com/add-javascript-in-blazor-components/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several ways to do this

1. [Inject a script after Blazor starts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#inject-a-script-after-blazor-starts)
   this is used to load js after blazor app started
2. [Load a script from an external JavaScript file (.js) collocated with a component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#load-a-script-from-an-external-javascript-file-js-collocated-with-a-component)
   on this way you can define a javascript file for each compponent
3. use your own javascript loader

this code can invoke callback function from blazor app. for this you must [register your instance first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0#invoke-an-instance-net-method) and you can call it from your blazor app

```
App = {};

App.LoadScript = (function (Url, Instance, CallBack) {
    var head = document.head;
    var IsExist = false;
    var Scripts = head.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = Scripts.length; i--;) {
        var Src = Scripts[i];
        if (Src.src == Url || Src.src.replace(Src.baseURI, '') == Url) {
            IsExist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!IsExist) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = Url;
        if (CallBack && Instance) {
            script.onload = setTimeout(() => { App.CsharpInvoker(Instance, CallBack); }, 3000);
        }
        else if (CallBack)
            script.onload = setTimeout(() => { CallBack(); }, 1000);

        head.appendChild(script);
    }
    else if (CallBack && Instance)
        setTimeout(() => { App.CsharpInvoker(Instance, CallBack); }, 1000);
    else if (CallBack)
        setTimeout(() => { CallBack(); }, 1000);
});

App.CsharpInvoker = (function CSharpCallBackInvoker(Instance, MethodName, Parameter) {
    Instance.invokeMethodAsync(MethodName, Parameter);
});
```

Comment: Second way worked